# Highstock Make a conditional tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I tried but no luck.

How can I make a conditional Tooltip using formatter? There's 3 lines on my Chart (more than 3k points), there's one line that it's just 0 or 1, these are like 0 = Off and 1 = On.

I want to show on the tooltip On and Off insted of 1 and 0.

The thing is, each serie has a personal tooltip to show decimals and suffix. I tried to use formatter there, but it simply does not work.

I tried

```
tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' ',
            yDecimals: 0,

                formatter: function() {
                    var s = this.y;

                    if (s == 1)
                        {
                            s = "ON";
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            s = "OFF";
                        }

                    return s;
                }                   
}
```

I can anything, like write "return '4'", but does not work.

Formatter only works on the Default tooltip :(

Any tips for this?

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/cvXZ9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take look at simple example, how it can work.

http://jsfiddle.net/q5eP3/

```
 tooltip:{
            formatter:function(){

                if(this.point.y == 0)
                    return 'ON'
                else
                    return 'OFF'

            }
        },
```

Comment: thanks, but, this only works on the default tooltip function, not the 'personal' series tooltip. check my sample: http://jsfiddle.net/cvXZ9/

Comment: Yes, in series tooltip only `pointFormat` (and similar patterns) works. How about setting that options for all other series, and default tooltip make with on/off?